# Send server message to connected clients with Signalr/PersistentConnection

Tags: signalr

I´m using SignalR/PersistentConnection, not the Hub.

I want to send a message from the server to client. I have the client id to send it, but how can I send a message from server to the client?

Like, when some event happens on server, we want send a notification to a particular user.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [github](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR) page shows how to do this using PersistentConnections.

```
public class MyConnection : PersistentConnection {
    protected override Task OnReceivedAsync(string clientId, string data) {
        // Broadcast data to all clients
        return Connection.Broadcast(data);
    }
}
```

Global.asax

```
using System;
using System.Web.Routing;
using SignalR.Routing;

public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication {
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        // Register the route for chat
        RouteTable.Routes.MapConnection<MyConnection>("echo", "echo/{*operation}");
    }
}
```

Then on the client:

```
$(function () {
    var connection = $.connection('echo');

    connection.received(function (data) {
        $('#messages').append('<li>' + data + '</li>');
    });

    connection.start();

    $("#broadcast").click(function () {
        connection.send($('#msg').val());
    });
});
```

Comment: This is the pertinent wiki page https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/QuickStart-Persistent-Connections

Comment: This assumes there's an incoming message to respond to.  How do you send a message to all connected clients on, say, a timer?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9472162/how-to-write-an-nlog-target-using-signalr seems to answer that, right?

Comment: Start a timer thread in app start in global asax and send data that way.

Comment: Would this approach work for a Hub too, or does it have to be the PersistentConnection?

Comment: Nevermind, I see it now in the DemoHub.cs and the Global.asax Application_Start of the samples.

Answer (score 1):

May be the AddToGroup function in the helps
in Server side

Put the clients in to different channels

```
public bool Join(string channel)
{
    AddToGroup(channel.ToString()).Wait();
    return true;
}
```

Then they Can send out message in different channel

```
public void Send(string channel, string message)
{

    String id = this.Context.ClientId;

    Clients[channel.ToString()].addMessage(message);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using SignalR;
using SignalR.Hosting.AspNet;
using SignalR.Infrastructure;

public class MyConnection : PersistentConnection
{
}

public class Notifier
{
  public void Notify(string clientId, object data) {
    MyConnection connection = (MyConnection) AspNetHost.DependencyResolver
      .Resolve<IConnectionManager()
      .GetConnection<MyConnection>();

    connection.Send(clientId, data);
  }
}
```

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/PersistentConnection