# How to write an NLog target using Signalr

Tags: nlog, signalr

I'm trying to write a target for NLog to send messages out to connected clients using SignalR.

Here's what I have now.  What I'm wondering is **should I be using resolving the ConnectionManager** like this **-or-** somehow **obtain a reference to the hub** (SignalrTargetHub) and call a SendMessage method on it?

Are there performance ramifications for either?

```
[Target("Signalr")]
public class SignalrTarget:TargetWithLayout
{

    public SignalR.IConnectionManager ConnectionManager { get; set; }

    public SignalrTarget()
    {
        ConnectionManager = AspNetHost.DependencyResolver.Resolve<IConnectionManager>();
    }

    protected override void Write(NLog.LogEventInfo logEvent)
    {

        dynamic clients = GetClients();

        var logEventObject = new
        {
            Message = this.Layout.Render(logEvent), 
            Level = logEvent.Level.Name,
            TimeStamp = logEvent.TimeStamp.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")
        };

        clients.onLoggedEvent(logEventObject);
    }

    private dynamic GetClients()
    {
        return ConnectionManager.GetClients<SignalrTargetHub>();
    }

}
```

Comment: https://github.com/cbley/NLog.SignalR, but it only sends 'rendered' string as single 'Message' property.

Comment: I'd like to see a NLog->SignalR bridge that sends both the original `Message`, and the rendered message (`MessageRendered` or `FullMessage`).

Answer (score 2):

I ended up with the basic the same basic structure that I started with.  Just a few tweaks to get the information I needed.

- Added exception details.
- Html encoded the final message.

---

```
[Target("Signalr")]  
public class SignalrTarget:TargetWithLayout  
{  
    protected override void Write(NLog.LogEventInfo logEvent)
    {
        var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(this.Layout.Render(logEvent));

        if (logEvent.Exception != null)
            sb.AppendLine().Append(logEvent.Exception.ToString());

        var message = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(sb.ToString());

        var logEventObject = new
        {
            Message = message,
            Logger = logEvent.LoggerName,
            Level = logEvent.Level.Name,
            TimeStamp = logEvent.TimeStamp.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff")
        };

        GetClients().onLoggedEvent(logEventObject);
    }

    private dynamic GetClients()
    {
        return AspNetHost.DependencyResolver.Resolve<IConnectionManager>().GetClients<SignalrTargetHub>();
    }
 }
```

In my simple testing it's working well.  Still remains to be seen if this adds any significant load when under stress.

Comment: I was just looking into this and found this post. how did this work out for you? did you create a client to receive these messages? would be awesome if you post a full example of this somewhere. sounds like a great idea!