# SignalR send message to single connectionId

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub

I have an asp.net classic website. ive got SignalR basic functionality to work (where one client send messages to rest of the clients). but now i want to send Messages only to specific connectionsIDs.

my Hub :

```
**    [HubName("chatHub")]
    public class ChatHub : Hub 
    {
        public static List<string> messages = new List<string>();

        public void GetServiceState()
        {
            Clients.updateMessages(messages);
        }

        public void UpdateServiceState()
        {
            messages.Add(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));

            Clients.updateMessages(messages);
        }

    }**
```

Asp code:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                // creates a proxy to the health check hub

                var healthCheckHub = $.connection.chatHub;
                console.log($.connection.hub)
                // handles the callback sent from the server
                healthCheckHub.updateMessages = function (data) {
                    $("li").remove();

                    $.each(data, function () {
                        $('#messages').append('<li>' + this + '</li>');
                        console.log($.connection);
                    });
                };

                $("#trigger").click(function () {
                    healthCheckHub.updateServiceState();
                });

                // Start the connection and request current state
                $.connection.hub.start(function () {
                    healthCheckHub.getServiceState();
                });


            });
```

Problem is i dont really know how to send to one specific ConnectionID with hub, since Clients.updateMessages(messages); send messages to all of them. how do i solve this?

P.S: ive already looked at: [Send server message to connected clients with Signalr/PersistentConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616983/send-server-message-to-connected-clients-with-signalr-persistentconnection)

and http://riba-escapades.blogspot.dk/2012/05/signalr-send-messages-to-single-client.html

that didnt worked.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Well, you can send a message to a single client from a Hub like so:

```
Clients.Client(someConnectionIdIWantToSendToSpecifically).doSomething();
```

The trick is you need to know the connection ID you want to send the message to. Even more specifically you probably want to know the logical identity of the thing you want to send the message too since that logical identity could have multiple connections or have dropped and reconnected under a completely different connection id. Mapping of connections to logical identities is something SignalR leaves up to the application itself.

Comment: I made it so that after user is logged in, connectionID will always be same as userID. In my Application i made it so that after user press send button, i find out who is folower for me and send messages only to those connection IDs. i dont know if that is a smart move. Any ideas how to implement it in smarter way?

Comment: Most of the implementations I've seen people doing use a one-to-many relationship mapping of logical user identity to active connection ids.

Comment: Last question, what would happend if i send message to a connectionID which is offline?

Comment: Don't really remember off the top of my head and don't have time to check right this second, but _pretty_ sure it's just a no-op to you. To check just try something like Client("abc123").foo() and see what happens.

Comment: What if I want to send the message to the specified connectionID and also to myself? How to solve this? please help

Comment: @Mr_Green To send the message to the current client you would just do: Clients.Caller.doSomething();

Comment: @DrewMarsh ok thank you for response.. after waiting for a while for your response, I asked this on SO, [please have a look, if you have time](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14155281/1577396) (It is somewhat different) :)