# Send message to specific client as well as the message sent user

Tags: jquery, asp.net, signalr

I am beginner in SignalR. I created a basic chat application based on SignalR. The problem I am facing is that I want to send message to the specific client as well as the user who sent the message. How to do this?

I know that to send a message to a specific client we can do this:

```
Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).addMessage(data);
```

which only sends message to the specified client not the one who sent the message.

I can even append the message at the user itself using jQuery giving a false belief that the message has been sent to the specified user. which I dont want to do.

PS: Can I use `done()` here? If yes, please explain?

**EDIT**:

**.js file**

```
txtMsg.keypress(function (e) {
   chat.server.send(chatUsername, selectedUsername, txtMsg.val(), showChatName, _invokeChat);
});

chat.client.addMessage = function (chatUsername, message, showChatName, invokeChat) {
    if (invokeChat) {
        selectedUsername = chatUsername;
        _invokeChat = false;
        chatTitleName.text("Chat with: " + selectedUsername);
    }
    if (showChatName) {
        //To show Username with the typed message
        showMessage.append('<b>' + chatUsername + '</b>' + ':&nbsp;' + message + '</br>');
    }
    else {
        //To show only typed message, not the username
        showMessage.append('&nbsp;&nbsp;' + message + '</br>');
    }
    previousUsername = chatUsername;
    //To keep scroll always bottom
    showMessage.scrollTop(showMessage[0].scrollHeight);
};
```

---

**.cs file** (*Changed by seeing Samir hafez answer*)

```
public void Send(string from, string to, string message, bool blnShowChatName, bool blnInvokeChat)
    {
        string ConnectionID = selectUsername(to);
        // Call the addMessage method on all clients    
        Clients.Client(ConnectionID).addMessage(from, message, blnShowChatName, blnInvokeChat);
        if (!from.Equals(to))
        {
            blnInvokeChat = false;
            Clients.Caller.addMessage(from, message, blnShowChatName, blnInvokeChat);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't bother sending the text back to the server. You could just use javascript to append the message

#### client

```
txtMsg.keypress(function (e) {
   chat.server.send(chatUsername, selectedUsername, txtMsg.val(), showChatName, _invokeChat);

   //add this message locally so we don't have to round trip to the server
   addMessage(chatUsername, txtMsg.val(), showChatName, _invokeChat);
});

chat.client.addMessage = addMessage;

function addMessage(chatUsername, message, showChatName, invokeChat) {
    if (invokeChat) {
        selectedUsername = chatUsername;
        _invokeChat = false;
        chatTitleName.text("Chat with: " + selectedUsername);
    }
    if (showChatName) {
        //To show Username with the typed message
        showMessage.append('<b>' + chatUsername + '</b>' + ':&nbsp;' + message + '</br>');
    }
    else {
        //To show only typed message, not the username
        showMessage.append('&nbsp;&nbsp;' + message + '</br>');
    }
        previousUsername = chatUsername;
    //To keep scroll always bottom
    showMessage.scrollTop(showMessage[0].scrollHeight);
};
```

#### server

```
public void Send(string from, string to, string message, bool blnShowChatName, bool blnInvokeChat)
    {
        string ConnectionID = selectUsername(to);
        // Call the addMessage method on all clients    
        Clients.Client(ConnectionID).addMessage(from, message, blnShowChatName, blnInvokeChat);
}
```

This simplifies your server code as well...

Comment: Can I do like this `chat.server.send(chatUsername, selectedUsername, txtMsg.val(), showChatName, _invokeChat).done(addMessage(chatUsername, txtMsg.val(), showChatName, _invokeChat));`  ?

Comment: The thing is that I dont want to append the function when connection failed.

Answer (score 2):

`Clients.Caller` will give you the calling client.

Or the more verbose way: `Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId)`

All this is available to you at the SignalR Wiki for Hubs [Here](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Hubs)

Comment: Here we are not specifying the specific clients ID then how does this work?

Comment: I am using `Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId)` in my code which is not showing message to the message sent user.

Comment: In `Clients.Caller` how we can call a specific client? (I dont know this, so I went with Verbose way)

Comment: The Clients.Caller property is only to send something for the caller, which is what you wanted. You can then make two calls: One for the end client with Client.Client(...) and one for the caller with Clients.Caller

Comment: I still don't fully understand: You want to know who is the client who sent the message, or you don't know how to send the message to its correct destination?

Comment: Hey its working but I am calling client twice.. which I dont like

Comment: `Clients.Client(ConnectionID).addMessage(from, message, blnShowChatName);`     
            `Clients.Caller.addMessage(from, message, blnShowChatName);`  any way to merge these two functions? so that I can call the client only once...

Comment: just because you access the Clients hubs twice doesn't mean you are hitting the client twice :)
the Clients hub is a gateway to all the connected clients, you just pick the ones you want. So I think what you did is correct

Comment: your explanation is correct, I have more doubts regarding the same. please check my updated post..

Comment: This is the only way to do it. You need to access one client (the recipient) and then another client (the caller). You will always make two client calls. The only way to avoid this is to have the javascript on your sender add the message through script and not use the server to send a copy of the message back to the caller.